# Trying to replace a cursor with update statement, went wrong somewhere

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `cursor` im trying to rewrite into a single `update` statement.

When comparing the results, I get 280 records that are being copied over with the `cursor` but NOT copied over with the `update` statement. Im pretty sure i rewrote the query correctly but the results disagrees with me. Can someone show me where i went wrong?

The `cursor`...

```
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BEGIN -- Explode MixMatch into UPCs
            SET @MixMatchToUPCCursor = CURSOR FOR
            SELECT
                MixMatch,
                VendorCode
            FROM
                PMS_MAIN
            WHERE
                adweekfromdate = @fromdate
                AND ltrim(rtrim(UPC12)) = ''

            OPEN @MixMatchToUPCCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM @MixMatchToUPCCursor
            INTO @MMToUPCMixAndMatch, @MMToUPCVendor

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    --INSERT INTO PMS_M_2
                    INSERT INTO PMS_MAIN (adweekfromdate, upc12, mixmatch, vendorcode, storeno, regioncode, hasdeal, usercomments)
                        SELECT
                            DISTINCT
                            @fromdate as FromDate,
                            UPCCodeUCC12 as UPC,
                            MixMatchCode as MM,
                            VendorCode as Vend,
                            '  ALL' as Store,
                            @regioncode as Reg,
                            1 as HasDeal,
                            'Exploded' as Comments
                        FROM
                            [wb-rtgsql].[RTG].[dbo].[StockMaster]
                        WHERE
                            MixMatchCode = @MMToUPCMixAndMatch
                            AND VendorCode = @MMToUPCVendor
                            AND UPCCodeUCC12 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN (SELECT
                                                                                  upc12
                                                                              FROM
                                                                                  PMS_MAIN
                                                                              WHERE
                                                                                  adweekfromdate = @fromdate AND MixMatch = @MMToUPCMixAndMatch AND VendorCode = @MMToUPCVendor)

                    FETCH NEXT FROM @MixMatchToUPCCursor
                    INTO @MMToUPCMixAndMatch, @MMToUPCVendor
                END

            CLOSE @MixMatchToUPCCursor
            DEALLOCATE @MixMatchToUPCCursor
        END -- Explode MixMatch into UPCs
```

What i have so far

```
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BEGIN -- Explode MixMatch into UPCs
            INSERT INTO PMS_MAIN (adweekfromdate, upc12, mixmatch, vendorcode, storeno, regioncode, hasdeal, usercomments)
            --INSERT INTO PMS_M_1
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT
                    @fromdate As FromDate,
                    SM.UPCCodeUCC12 as UPC,
                    SM.MixMatchCode as MM,
                    SM.VendorCode AS Vend,
                    '  ALL' as Store,
                    @regioncode as Reg,
                    1 as HasDeal,
                    'Exploded' as Comments
                FROM
                    [WB-RTGSQL].RTG.dbo.StockMaster AS SM INNER JOIN
                    dbo.PMS_MAIN AS Main
                        ON SM.VendorCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Main.vendorcode AND SM.MixMatchCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Main.mixmatch 
                WHERE
                    Main.Upc12 = ''
                    --AND Main.vendorcode + main.mixmatch in

        END
```

How i am comparing my results

```
SELECT *
FROM   PMS_M_1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM   PMS_M_2
   WHERE  PMS_M_1.upc COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = PMS_M_2.upc
        and PMS_M_1.mm COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = PMS_M_2.mm
        and PMS_M_1.vend COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = PMS_M_2.vend)
```

E: `PMS_M_1` and `PMS_M_2` are Tables I created with only the columns I need for the sake of comparing my results. Updated code to reflect.

Comment: your cursor's `WHERE adweekfromdate = @fromdate` is not present in your re-written statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
      INSERT INTO PMS_MAIN (adweekfromdate, upc12, mixmatch, vendorcode, storeno, regioncode, hasdeal, usercomments)
                            SELECT
                                DISTINCT
                                @fromdate as FromDate,
                                UPCCodeUCC12 as UPC,
                                MixMatchCode as MM,
                                VendorCode as Vend,
                                '  ALL' as Store,
                                @regioncode as Reg,
                                1 as HasDeal,
                                'Exploded' as Comments
                            FROM
                                [wb-rtgsql].[RTG].[dbo].[StockMaster]
                            WHERE
                                MixMatchCode = @MMToUPCMixAndMatch
                                AND VendorCode = @MMToUPCVendor
                                AND not exists (SELECT   upc12
                         FROM  PMS_MAIN
WHERE  adweekfromdate = @fromdate and AND ltrim(rtrim(UPC12)) = ''
    and UPCCodeUCC12 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=upc12 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
```